# perl outlook printf to show subfolders created in a script

Tags: perl

Hi I have a script that creates outlook email sub folders each month, how can i show via printf the folders that have just been created.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';

my $Outlook;
eval { $Outlook = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application') };
die "Outlook not installed" if $@;
unless ( defined $Outlook ) {
    $Outlook = Win32::OLE->new( 'Outlook.Application', sub { $_[0]->Quit; } )
        or die "Oops, cannot start Outlook";
}
my $namespace = $Outlook->GetNamespace("MAPI");

my $Folder = $namespace->Folders("admin")->Folders("Inbox")->Folders->Add("test");
my $folder = $namespace->Folders("admin")->Folders("Inbox")->Folders("test")->Folders->Add("12");
$folder = $namespace->Folders("admin")->Folders("Inbox")->Folders("test")->Folders->Add("123");
$folder = $namespace->Folders("admin")->Folders("Inbox")->Folders("test")->Folders->Add("1234");

#
foreach my $i ( 1 .. $namespace->Folders->Count ) {
    $folder = $namespace->Folders($i)->Name;
    print "Folder:  $folder\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 12 months possible, so you can do something like this:

```
my @months = qw( JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC );
```

then use a foreach loop perhaps like this:

```
for my $months (@months) {
    print "...path/samplefolder/$month";
}
```

Comment: yes, my bad.. the post was edited earlier by someone, seems he forgot the 's'. I had originally used a 'foreach' instead of the 'for'. Are you sure it doesn't changes the output?